# I have 100 mb internet connection but am downloading at 35 KB. What's the deal?

Tags: networking

I have 100 mb internet spped according to the status page in my OS.  However, currently downloading at 35 KB, dial up speed?

Comment: Your OS cannot tell your ISP's speed. Just because you are connected via a 100 Mbps cable doesn't imply your ISP provides you a 100 Mbps connection.

Comment: Please don't ask technical questions without including technical details. What equipment? How are you measuring? Also, what are you communicating (or not) with your unit capitalization? Is "mb" megabits, as in 1,000,000's of individual bits per second? Is your "KB" KibiBytes, as in 1,024's of 8-bit Bytes per second? Or is your "KB" kilobits, as in 1,000's of individual bits per second? You say "dial-up speed" which would imply kilobits, but the fact that you capitalized it whereas you didn't capitalize "mb" throws me off enough I thought I should ask.

Answer (score 1):

OK, a few things:

1. I suspect that you do not 100mbit access to the Internet. (Which is something which your OS will **not** show. However it will show the link speed to your LAN. That is not the same thing.
2. Nitpick: 35KB/sec is very much not dial up speed. It is way more than that.
3. Your Speed to the Internet is limited by both your desktop, your switch, your modem, any system beteen you and the destination, and finally the machine you are downloading from. Any of these could be slowing things down.

Answer (score 1):

Your download speed depends on lots of different factors. Every system in the path between your computer and the server you are downloading from play some part.

Based on your description, you are on a wired connection. The speed reported by your OS is only the speed of your local network, that is the speed between your computer and the router or modem. Your internet speed is something entirely different, as is the speed of the server you are downloading from.

Other factors may be the number of people also on your network (wired and wireless) and what they're using the internet for, the number of people downloading the same thing you are or downloading something different from the same server, the number of people watching TV in your neighborhood (if you have cable internet).

In other words, that 100Mbps speed is only one very small part of your whole internet download speed picture.

Answer (score 0):

Your isp may be providing you with 100mb download speeds, but that does not mean that downloads from any particular site will make use of that. What you are experiencing is a bottleneck with your content provider - their servers may only be capable of 1mb speeds. In cases where you are able to get good speeds, the content provider probably has good servers.

You can try downloading at "off-peak" times (late nights where the content is located) or via torrents if they have that capability.

The problem is not with your internet provider, it is with the site from which you are trying to download.